# New application only working within the developers browser. Is this somehow the code I have created?

Tags: facebook-apps

I have designed and created my first application. I can supply the html if needed.

Now I can see the application working in my desktop browser BUT when other people try to test the application it does not work. They experience an error which reads like this = https://www.facebook.com/4oh4.php

The application is https://apps.facebook.com/lbrguineascomp/

Is there a setting or code that is somehow blocking anyone other than the actual developer to see and use this basic quiz type application? The same happens on mobile phones

Comment: Do check the settings for `Sandbox` option in your App Settings page.

Comment: Thanks Anvesh - indeed that was the problem!

Answer (score 0):

As of 4th April, 2013 Facebook has started to default new applications to **sandbox mode** by default which could cause problem of displaying [404](https://www.facebook.com/4oh4.php) on accessing application by anyone other than mentioned people in its **App Settings** page. The same was mentioned in this [blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/04/03/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/).